# Is everything behind a secure proxy secure?

Tags: security, ssl, cookies, nginx, hapi.js

After taking a look at the [HTTP State Management Mechanism Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) specifically [4.1.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.5) where it mentions:

> The Secure attribute limits the scope of the cookie to "secure"
> channels (where "secure" is defined by the user agent).  When a
> cookie has the Secure attribute, the user agent will include the
> cookie in an HTTP request only if the request is transmitted over a
> secure channel (typically HTTP over Transport Layer Security (TLS)

I was wondering if my setup has this set up correctly. I have a hapijs server and an nginx proxy server that it sits behind. The nginx server is configured for HTTPS (I can access it via https://..., anyway). Now there are ways to provide certs to the hapijs server to provide it TLS. My question is: is this necessary? The connection between the user's browser and my server is protected with TLS and then all that communication happens without sending anything over the wire so I would assume it would be okay.

I may be way off base here so maybe someone can point me in the right direction if I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "secure" attribute of cookies is handled by the client (the web browser) and not by any proxy servers (at least that that I'm aware of!).

So you should be fine as long as the endpoint the browser connects to is secure.

This is a very common set up to only secure traffic at the end point - providing you are comfortable with the the security of the link between endpoint and final destination (e.g. same machine or internal network).

Of course an internal network traffic can be sniffed by someone onsite (e.g. an employee) so https all the way is best from a security point of view, but using http from endpoint to final destination should not prevent "secure" cookies being sent on from my experience.

If using external network as the first server (e.g. CDN) then it's strongly advisable to use https all the way to a secure endpoint, though again they will not be stopped.

Comment: I mean this makes sense - the part where you talk about using HTTPS all the way through - but I cannot find any information on how to make that connection secure.

Comment: What do you mean? You don't know how to configure hapijs for https?

Comment: Sorry what I'm referring to is regarding your comment "so https all the way is best from a security point of view".I have a cert from LetsEncrypt for the nginx proxy. But how would I go about securing the connection from nginx to hapi. That cert, and maybe I'm wrong, wouldn't make sense to reuse as hapi is no longer browser-facing. Hapi should just assume the connection with nginx is trusted, but I haven't found any information online to *guarantee* that the connection is secure.

Comment: Hapi doesn't know it's secure (other than the fact the cookies have arrived) so yes it has to assume it is. I presume your hapi server is not directly accessible from outside world except through Nginx? If so then that's your security there and you have to put trust in your Nginx setup.

Comment: Hapi can either be contacted from Nginx over http, or if you want an extra layer of security, over https. You won't be able to reuse that cert as the name won't match (unless it's over same server in which case https is even less necessary) but you could use a self-signed cert and set up Nginx to trust that. Probably more hassle than it's worth and leaving that Nginx - Hapi part over http is, as I say, fairly standard for now.

Comment: Ah thank you! I hadn't even considered self-signed certs for that. But after asking around I believe I also agree that the tunnel between hapi and nginx just being http is sufficient. I believe this is also how Amazon does it with their ELB. My hapi and nginx instance are on the same server (I'm just trying to learn this stuff) so I think I have my answer. Again, thank you.